# Как назвать самца белки?

Tags: словообразование

И еще вопрос из серии "как называется". Как назвать самца белки одним словом? У всех животных, чье название звучит в мужском роде, есть женская форма: заяц — зайчиха, олень — олениха, волк — волчица. А вот у белки, получается, только женский род?

Comment: Самец белки - *мальчик*

Comment: Хм... Ну да. 

"-- Мальчик, -- сказал Остап, -- разве плох? *Типичный
мальчик.* Кто скажет, что это девочка, пусть первый бросит
в меня камень!" (с)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из "белка" легко восстанавливается *бела* или *бел*.
Предположу, что когда-то так оно и было, но ныне совершенно утрачено.

//==========================================================

Насчет цвета.

Автор: "Справочное бюро" 
Дата:   06-02-02 20:16

Цитируем: "...Сначала, м. б., говорили бела веверица (ср. др.-рус. вЪверица - "белка" - Срезневский ...). Это простое объяснение ... не устраняет одного вопроса: почему белка была названа белой веверицей, когда обычная окраска ее шерсти красновато-рыжая. Но такая порода белки могла существовать в Древней Руси. Ср. любопытнейшее свидетельство путешественника Рычкова ("Журнал" за 1769 и 1770 гг., 176): "Между белками, ловимыми в Камских лесах, изредка попадаются совесм белые, которых ловцы называют князьями беличьего рода" (далее рассказывается о сарапульском жителе Воеводском, который долго хранил одну шкурку такого "беличьего князька"). Кроме того, имеется очень редкая теперь порода голубой белки, которая также могла быть названа белой в отличие от рыжей или черной (такая окраска также встречается)" (Черных П. Я. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка. Т. 1. М., 1999). А почему не задали вопрос "Справочному бюро"? Другим (кто не бывает на "Вече") тоже интересно.

http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=1&i=1473&t=1461

Answer (score 2):

Не у всех названий животных есть формы женского и мужского рода. Хоть "*собака*" Вам в пример: если разделять на "он" и "она", то совсем другие слова получаются. И ворон с вороной - тоже не муж и жена.

Так что - самец белки, по-другому никак.

Comment: У собаки-то как раз есть ***пёс***.

Comment: Нее, пес и собака — это одно и то же))) Просто, у домашних животных по половому признаку вообще другие названия.

Comment: Вы можете себе представить самку пса?

Comment: Вполне. Она называется сука.

Comment: Всегда считала, что по половому признаку антоним суке - кобель, а не пес.

Comment: Вот Вы и нашли слово для белки-мальчика : ко/бель, ко/белина...

Comment: Это ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Самец белки - **белка**, самка - **бельчиха** (разг). В целом, далеко не все животные, получают различие по половому признаку (*крот, песец, бобр, норка, куница, антилопа*).

Answer (score 0):

Вот мне тут подкинули, что у охотников есть название "белёк" или "бел**о**к". Не знаю, насколько верно.